# Use Proc as a key for caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, block, proc

I am trying to cache rails request to an external service which takes a proc.

For me to be able to differentiate 2 requests, its important that the proc is part of the Rails cache key.

However multiple requests with the same proc and the values in the proc code, would still evaluate to a different proc object each time.

Eg:

```
#<Proc:0x007ff6f675dd08@/Users/app/development/work/runner.rb:10>
#<Proc:0x007ff6ffb50790@/Users/app/development/work/runner.rb:10>
```

Hence , I get cache miss even for same requests.

How do I use the block/proc in the cache key that evaluates to same if the procs are same in terms of code and variable values.

The service call is something like

```
def some_method    
  call_service do 
    a= 3;
    b=6
  end
end

 def call_service(block)
       Rails.cache.fetch(Date.today, block) {
         external_service(&block)
       }
  end

 I want to be able to compare blocks :
eg 
{a=3, a*a} == {a=3, a*a}  => True
{a=3, a*a} == {a=4, a*a}  => false
{a=3, a*a} == {a=4, a*a*a} => False
```

I tried to use,

```
block.source
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.of(block).disasm
```

But none of them captures the state of the block, i.e the values of the variables (a=3 etc)

What the best way to achieve this type of caching in rails ?

P.S:

Using Rails4 and reddis as the cache

Answer (score 0):

Each time you define an *inline block* with `do ... end` you will get a *different* Proc object. You will have to go out of your way to be absolutely certain you're sending through exactly the same Proc:

```
def some_method    
  @my_call ||= lambda {
    a = 3
    b = 6
  }

  call_service(&@my_call)
end
```

This is probably a bad idea from the outset. What you'd be better off doing is passing in a cache key:

```
call_service("3/6") do
  # ...
end
```

Then you cache against this consistent key, not the arbitrary Proc.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some mileage this way. This function returns a simple Proc object. The object will have a source location and a binding that contains the state of arguments a, b and c when the Proc was built.

```
def build_proc(a, b, c)
  Proc.new { puts "I was built with params #{a} #{b} #{c}!" }
end
```

So we can build our Proc objects--

```
2.0.0-p195 :121 > p1 = build_proc(1, 2, 3)
=> #<Proc:0x98849e8@(irb):118> 
2.0.0-p195 :122 > p2 = build_proc(2, 4, 6)
=> #<Proc:0x985e57c@(irb):118>
```

To get the state of an argument you can call `binding.eval('argument')` against a Proc object. This runs code in the context of that Proc's binding. So you can say--

```
p1.binding.eval('[a, b, c]') == p2.binding.eval('[a, b, c]')

2.0.0-p195 :127 > p1.binding.eval('[a, b, c]') == p2.binding.eval('[a, b, c]')
 => false 
2.0.0-p195 :128 > p2 = build_proc(1, 2, 3)
 => #<Proc:0x97ae4b0@(irb):118> 
2.0.0-p195 :129 > p1.binding.eval('[a, b, c]') == p2.binding.eval('[a, b, c]')
 => true
```

And obviously you can compare source locations--

```
p1.source_location == p2.source_location && 
p1.binding.eval('[a, b, c]') == p2.binding.eval('[a, b, c]')
```

You'd need a way to extract the arguments out of the binding in a universal way and you'd want to combine their hashes rather than build an array for comparison (e.g. `'a.hash ^ b.hash ^ c.hash'`).

This does feel horrible though! At the very least, overriding `:==` on Procs is probably a bad idea.